# Trying to solve a system of equation with a subscripted variable with Reduce

Tags: equation-solving, subscript

When I run `Reduce[expr, vars]` in which one of the variables has a subscript, Mathematica gives me an output after some minutes (the system has 10 equations), but if I change the variable with the subscript for a variable without it, Mathematica freezes after some time and does not give any answer.

I have tried to solve other systems with lesser dimensions, trying with some variables subscripted or trying with all variables non-subscripted, but the output is the same.

I don't know what is happening. I need the results but I don't know if I can trust them when I have a variable with a subscript.
The system is

```
q = 1 - m^2/2 - 2 v^2 - w^2 + z^2 + Σ^2;
fx = x (q - 1 - 2 Σ) - 2 s p Subscript[ξ, j];
fy = y (Σ + q - 1) - Subscript[ξ, j] (p^2 + s^2 + w^2);
fw = w (Subscript[ξ, j] y + q - Σ) + Sqrt[2] Subscript[ξ, j] s z;
fz = z (q - 2) - w Subscript[ξ, j] (α v + Sqrt[2] s);
fv = v (q + 1) + α Subscript[ξ, j] w z;
fr = r (q - 1);
fm = m (q - 1/2);
fp = p (q - 1 + Σ+y ξ) +s x Subscript[ξ, j] ;
fs = s (2 y Subscript[ξ, j] - 2 Σ + q - 1);
fΣ = Σ (q - 2) - (p^2 - s^2) + w^2 - y^2 + x^2;
Subscript[fξ, j] = Subscript[ξ, j] (1 - Subscript[ξ, j] y + Σ);
```

And the function

```
Reduce[
  {fx == 0, fy == 0, fw == 0, fz == 0, fv == 0, fm == 0, fp == 0, fs == 0, 
   fΣ == 0, Subscript[fξ, j] == 0}, 
  {x, y, w, z, v, m, p, s, Σ, Subscript[ξ, j]}];
```

I have Mathematica 10.2.

Comment: Please include code, otherwise we would not be able to give you specific answers. If you just need to check the accuracy of the results, you should be able to just substitute the results back into the original equation and see if it is satisfied.

Comment: @MarcoB makes a good suggestion for checking the results.  Even simpler is to substitute numbers for some or all of your variables e.g `result /. x->5` (see `ReplaceAll` in the help).

Comment: `Subscript[fξ, j] == 0` looks suspicious. Shouldn't it be `Subscriptfξ, j] == 0`

Comment: I don't understand the reason behind removing the "[" in your suggestion @m_goldberg.

Comment: Sorry, reviewing your code makes me think I read it wrong the 1st time. I see no problem on rereading.

Comment: The code in the question does not yield a solution for me with either Mathermatica 11.3 or 12.0 on Windows 10, even after several hours of computation.  Are you sure that the code in the question is what you used to obtain a solution in" some minutes"?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, yes, I obtain a solution after approximately 20 min, but only when I let the variable ξ subscripted, I have Mathematica 10.2 in Ubuntu.

Comment: Very strange.  This may be a bug in Mathematica.  Hard to say.

Comment: What, ultimately, do you wish to accomplish?  Perhaps, obtaining a general solution to the eleven equations above?  I believe that I can obtain it, although not easily.,

Comment: Yes @bbgodfrey, I want to obtain a general solution of the whole system, I would appreciate a lot if you could explain to me how to do it. Also, I've solved the system putting α as a variable in the command Solve[], the answer was rather quick, but I don't know the scope of the generality of this solution.

Comment: `Solve` should provide most answers but often ignores conditional requirements, like `y != 0`.  To get all answers, use `Reduce`.  Note that both `Solve` and `Reduce` often use "GroebnerBasis` for difficult computations, and the speed at which it proceeds can depends sensitively on the order of the variables.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, Redefining the variables I decreased the degree of the equations to 3, nevertheless the system is still unsolved, I tried with both `Solve` and `Reduce` commands. I used `α` as a variable in the `Solve` command and it yielded a solution, this is not what I'm looking for given that `α` is a parameter, the dependence of the solutions on the parameter is something that would lead to different models for each solution, that's why is unfortunate.

Comment: Unless `α` can be eliminated entirely from the equations, some solutions inevitably will depend on it.